# Warning 1261 Row n doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a requirement to load data from a CSV file into a Mysql Table in Windows 10.
The command I am using in MySQL Workbench 8.0.20 is:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Sample.txt" IGNORE INTO TABLE TableA
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8,
 col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15,
 dummy_1, dummy_2, dummy_3, dummy_4, dummy_5) ;
```

The original input file was *Sample.csv*. 
When I ran the LOAD cmd I got the error

> Error 1261    Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns.

Similar error for Rows 2 - 13.

I saved the CSV file as a Text file ( *Sample.txt* ) using Notepad. I got the same errors for the text file. It is only giving errors for the first 13 rows in the text file. So I deleted the first 13 rows and ran the LOAD again. I still get the same warnings for rows 1 to 13 only.

FYI, Each row does not have the same number of Fields.
Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear and just says that some of the lines in your CSV text file do not have 20 data points.  You may try using the following regex pattern to highlight rows in the file which do not match:

```
^(?!(?:[^,]*,){19}[^,]*$).*$
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry..I am not familiar with using regex. Can the regex pattern be used in a SQL statement ?

Comment: @JayJohn Well I am suggesting that you do a regex find on your file `Sample.txt`, to highlight the rows which are not matching.  You can't use SQL yet, because you don't even have a table.

Comment: Does the Regex pattern that you have given above count the number of commas in the file ? I am trying to understand what exactly it stands for. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jay, the regex pattern asserts that the lines does _not_ have 19 commas (= 20 terms).  If so, then such a line would be missing data for all 20 columns in your insert query.

Comment: No, it is not clear @TimBiegeleisen. I'm experiencing the same issue. Looks like mySQL doesn't parse correctly csv files that comes with \n. I checked with a python script using csv reader. All my rows contain 4 valid fields, despite of that, mySQL says in some row, I don't have enough fields ‍♂️